# Autoscaling: Unable to reach resize target for the worker pool in zone us-central1-f

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am running a pipeline using the Apache Beam model in Google Cloud Dataflow but I am unable to scale it up from 8 workers, even though the maximum number of workers is 32.

When I try to run the same pipeline setting the number of workers to 32, it gives me the following warnings:

`Autoscaling: Startup of the worker pool in zone us-central1-f reached 30 workers, but the goal was 32 workers. The service will retry. QUOTA_EXCEEDED: Quota 'DISKS_TOTAL_GB' exceeded.  Limit: 4096.0`

`Autoscaling: Unable to reach resize target in zone us-central1-f. QUOTA_EXCEEDED: Quota 'DISKS_TOTAL_GB' exceeded.  Limit: 4096.0`

But still doesn't pass 8 workers. Is there any particular reasons why a pipeline won't use more than 8 workers?

Comment: You don't have quota for 32. Can you try with a max of 30 workers?

Is this streaming or batch and if you can, do you have a dataflow job id?

It should be using the 30 in this case as well. It stays at 8? The UI may be out of date in this case. We can check with the job id.

Comment: I tried without setting any restrictions, letting the autoscaling work by itself, and the number of workers scale to 8, try to reach a target of 11 but fails and stays at 8. The job ID is 2017-09-01_04_00_51-11489162724292257643.

Comment: I run again the same pipeline but got a new error related to quote, this sound more likely related to the problem:

```Autoscaling: Unable to reach resize target in zone us-central1-f. QUOTA_EXCEEDED: Quota 'IN_USE_ADDRESSES' exceeded.  Limit: 8.0```

Comment: This would be the reason. When there are multiple quota violations, Dataflow highlights an arbitrary one. Additional error messages can be found in Stackdriver Logging in the GCE VM Instance logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was quota limits. Google Dataflow uses behind the scenes VMs of Google Compute Engine and their quotas apply. The specific limitation of 8 was being caused by the In use external IP adresses quota limitation. Others quotas were also violated when I tried to scale to 32, like the Disk space. So if anyone is having the same problem I suggest going to `IAM Admin > Quotas` on the console while the pipeline is running to check which quotas your pipeline may violate.

Also, the logs are different if you run using a deployed template or use the Eclipse plugin to run in debug mode. The later will give much more details than the first.

Answer (score 1):

1. Visit https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas
2. Use the filter menu that says Quota type

   [image]
3. You can tell by the color of the Current Usage column that API limit has reached limit.
4. Click **Edit Quotas** for the API that has exceeded usage and request for new limit. This will take from few hours to day.

Answer (score 0):

Dataflow will use whatever number of workers you can get. In your case, it will reach 30 workers and will use them. It will however retry constantly to reach 32, as quota could be given back by other workflows.

Comment: It didn't. It is using only 8 workers, with or without autoscaling.